# Taking screenshot from HWND from PID

Tags: c++, windows, screenshot

I am currently creating a way to take screenshots of windows. Right now I am specifying the PID of the application I want to take a screenshot of. I am getting the HWNDs that are associated with that PID by using this function

```
void GetAllWindowsFromProcessID(DWORD dwProcessID, std::vector <HWND> &vhWnds) {
    // find all hWnds (vhWnds) associated with a process id (dwProcessID)
    HWND hCurWnd = nullptr;
    do {
        hCurWnd = FindWindowEx(nullptr, hCurWnd, nullptr, nullptr);
        DWORD checkProcessID = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, &checkProcessID);
        if (checkProcessID == dwProcessID) {
            vhWnds.push_back(hCurWnd);
        }
    } while (hCurWnd != nullptr);
}
```

Once I have a vector of the HWNDs associated with that PID I loop through with my screenshot code and save the screenshot of each one.

When I run this code with Notepad++ (PID 712) I get 7 HWNDs associated with the PID. I have checked all 7 of them and they all print a black screen except the last one, which prints the Notepad++. If I try this on Notepad or Calculator I just get a black screen.

Full testing code that I am using..

```
snip
```

Comment: Are you sure your screenshot code is OK? Can you run it with the HWND of the Calculator that you get from Spy++? Is the image also black?

Comment: Found it in the Spy++ program. Going to try to hardcode this handle.

Comment: There is a "Find Window" command, Ctrl+F, with a "cross-hair" icon in it - just drag it over the window you are interested in.

Comment: Ok I just tried it using the calculator handle. I know it altered the calculator because I am changing the opacity to the window. And I am able to see it get transparent, so I know I have the right handle. But it did not capture a SS. Then I tried again using the Notepad++ handle using the same method and that worked.

Comment: It kinda points to an issue with your Screen Capture code; looks like it can't capture transparent windows?

Comment: I added the full code. You should be able to just paste that into VS. You can hard code the handle, or you can read the comment for testing.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetClientRect` on the desktop window instead of your particular HWND?

Comment: You seem to be passing trash to the second parameter of `GdiplusStartup`

Comment: The first parameter to `ReleaseDC` is wrong.

Comment: The `Bitmap::Bitmap` constructor says "Do not pass to the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap constructor a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context"  You are passing a GDI bitmap that was previously selected into a device context.  I don't know what this function is good for with that restriction.  Also, the second parameter where you are passing `nullptr` is optional only for DIBs.  You have created a compatible bitmap not a DIB.

Comment: Well, `CreateCompatibleBitmap` *can* create a DIB if a DIB was already selected into the device context.  Might explain why your results are so dependent on what program you try to capture.

Comment: FYI, `GetAllWindowsFromProcessID()` should be using `EnumWindows()` instead of a `FindWindowEx()` loop

Comment: Calling GetClientRect on desktop window instead of HWND because I was originally testing to the full desktop. Changing this to the specific hwnd doesn't change anything. GdiplusStartup is allowed to have trash as second parameter, have a look at the docs. ReleaseDC is fine, have a look at docs. GetAllWindowsFromProcessID() works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer yet (I just need to post a screenshot).

Here is what I see in Spy++:

[image]

You may want to try a child window `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`, for example.